# 406 Error with Mechanize

Tags: python, mechanize

I'm getting a 406 error with Mechanize when trying to open a URL:

```
for url in urls:
    if "http://" not in url: 
        url = "http://" + url
    print url
    try:
        page = mech.open("%s" % url)
    except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
        print "there was an error opening the URL, logging it"
        print e.code
        logfile = open ("log/urlopenlog.txt", "a")
        logfile.write(url + "," + "couldn't open this page" + "\n")
        continue
    else:
        print "opening this URL..."
        page = mech.open(url)
```

Any idea what would cause a 406 error to occur? If I go to the URL in question I can open it in the browser.

Comment: No need to use interpolation there: `page = mech.open(url)` will do just fine (though not a fix for your problem).

Comment: The 406 error is very specific to a web server. It *means* that the server doesn't like your `Accept` header, in any case.

Comment: [406 means that the server doesn't like your headers](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) Can you post the headers that mechanize sends?

Comment: Try adding `Accept` headers (see http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/doc.html#adding-headers), check what your browser sends..

Comment: `406 Not Acceptable
The requested resource is only capable of generating content not acceptable according to the Accept headers sent in the request.` Time to dig up Wireshark or Fiddler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding headers to your request based on what your browser sends; start with adding an `Accept` header (406 normally means the server didn't like what you want to accept).

See ["Adding headers"](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/doc.html#adding-headers) in the documentation:

```
req = mechanize.Request(url)
req.add_header('Accept', 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8')
page = mechanize.urlopen(req)
```

The `Accept` header value there is based on the header sent by Chrome.

Comment: @user1328021: This depends entirely on the server, there is no easy answer. Add headers that you find your browser is sending when accessing the same URL until it works.

Comment: My browser show that it is sending that exact header above. What about `Accept-Language` or `Accept-Encoding`? Could those have an effect?

Comment: @user1328021: *any* header could have an effect, if the server so chooses. The `Accept-*` headers are the first I'd try though.

Comment: Ok awesome! My problem was the `User-Agent` header. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find out which headers your browser sends, this webpage shows them to you: https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-http-headers-is-my-browser-sending

The 'Accept' and 'User-Agent' headers should be enough. This is what I did to get rid of the error:

```
#establish counter
j = 0

#Create headers for webpage
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0', 'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8'}

#Create for loop to get through list of URLs
for url in URLs:

    #Verify scraper agent so that web security systems don't block webpage scraping upon URL opening, with j as a counter
    req = mechanize.Request(URLs[j], headers = headers)

    #Open the url
    page = mechanize.urlopen(req)

    #increase counter
    j += 1
```

You could also try importing the "urllib2" or "urllib" libraries to open these URLs. The syntax is the same.